# Angular service does not update in controller

Tags: angularjs

I am building a quiz in Angular and Im using a factory function to load the question database.

```
angular
    .module('myQuiz')
    .factory('QuestionService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

        var currentQuestion = 0;

        return {

            getQuestion: function() {   

            var def = $q.defer();

            $http.get("quizdb.json")
                .success(function(data) {
                    // resolve the data by returning the question, choices and correctanswer in an object
                    def.resolve({
                        totalQuestions: data.allQuestions.length,
                        question: data.allQuestions[currentQuestion].question,
                        choices: data.allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices,
                        correctAnswer: data.allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer
                        });
                })
                .error(function() {
                    def.reject("failed to retrieve questions");
                });
            return def.promise; 
            },
            getCurrentQuestion: function() {
                return currentQuestion;
            },
            nextQuestion: function() {
                (currentQuestion >= 0) ? currentQuestion += 1 : false; 
            }, 
            prevQuestion: function() {
                (currentQuestion < 0) ? false : currentQuestion -= 1; 
            }
        };
}]);
```

When the user clicks on the "next" button it will call the nextQuestion in this factory. This is correctly updated in the factory, but I dont know how to get the up-to-date value in my controller. I dont think $watch will work and a timeout function seemss a bit of a hack. Maybe its better to use a value service to hold the currentQuestion variable?

Additional question, should I keep the question logic in the current factory or is it better to create a seperate one?

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not just call `getCurrentQuestion()` to get the question, or if you need to do it all in one step, just return the current question from `nextQuestion`.

```
        getCurrentQuestion: function() {
            return currentQuestion;
        },
        nextQuestion: function() {
            (currentQuestion >= 0) ? currentQuestion += 1 : false;
             return curretQuestion;
        },
```

Comment: This might sound stupid, but how do i capture the returned value?

  function addQuestion() {
   vm.selected = false; 
   QuestionService.nextQuestion();
   getTheCurrentQuestion();
  }

Comment: $scope.variable_name =QuestionService.nextQuestion();

Comment: But that was my initial question, it will only reflect it once in the controller because it only gets called one time. It will return 1 every time. I dont understand that behavior at all. The value service could work, but it doesnt allow me to increment a number.

Comment: You said the user clicks a Next button. So you are calling a function when that happens in your controller. That function must call QuestionService.nextQuestion(); . and save the returned value into another variable in the controller. The chain of events will happen on every user click

Comment: I obviously used that logic, but it doesnt work for some odd reason. Im really done with angular for tonight.